# Laravel 5.2 /login & /register not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm testing out the new Laravel and when creating a basic application

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel
composer install
composer update
php artisan make:auth
```

I'm presented with the basic authentication scaffold, after doing a little playing around, the links on the menu for logging in and registers stop working. I coudn't find the problem to fix it so I just created a new project.

And the same has happened again.

All i've done is

1. Created a new view *members.dashboard*
2. Set the login redirect to go to the dash board after logging in

Has anyone seen this problem before and can point me to the error?

UPDATE

```
/auth/login = no route
/auth/register = no route
/login = redirect to home page
/register = redirect to home page
```

Comment: is `/auth/login` OR `/auth/register` accessible?

Comment: have you tried deleting the cookies? what happens when you access login URL after deleting the cookies?

Comment: @eMAD i've updated the question

Comment: are all your routes that are using that layout in the 'web' middleware group ?

Comment: `/login = redirect to home page`
`/register = redirect to home page`
means you are logged in

Comment: @eMAD yeah deleting the cookies got it. Thanks a bunch

Comment: You were logged in & cookies were keeping track of your authentication status. In Laravel Auth, Logged-In users can't view `login` page or `register` page.

Comment: @DaleSnowdon has the answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were logged in & cookies were keeping track of your authentication status.
Thus you are redirected to `home page` when you visit

```
/login
/register
```

In Laravel Auth, Logged-In users can't view `login` page or `register` page. You have to either logout OR delete the cookies (not a recommended way) to view these pages again.

Comment: but what if I would like to create new user with my admin account (=register new one) and don't want public to register .. how can I do that?

Comment: Make that **Create new User** page's URL accessible only to user who is **logged-in** as well as his role is **admin**.

Comment: I did it but when I try to access /register route, it doesn't work ... nothing happen

Comment: You do not need the default functionality of **Auth** routes (Especially that of `/register`). You should create a Custom **Create new User** page and *create a new private **route** (say `/add-user`) for this page*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making mention to the 'Login' and 'Register' links the layout supplies, they work fine.

By default the '/' route doesn't have the 'web' middleware group applied, so no sessions/auth. Auth will think you are not logged in if you don't have that middleware group applied to any routes where you need to use Auth.